# Use (hidden) URL query parameters to re-use the email and password in the signup page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a NextJS app with a login page. If the user enters a email that is not linked to an existing account, I want to show a button to redirect the user to the signup page.

Ideally, I would like the email and password entered in the login page to be pre-filled in the signup page.

I currently show a link:

```js
<Link
  href={{
    pathname: '/signup',
    query: {
      email,
      password
    },
  }}
  as={'/signup'}
  passHref
>
  Go to signup
</Link>
```

The entered `email` and `password` are in the query params, but thanks to the `as='/signup'` property, they don't show in the browser address bar.

In my signup page I can fetch them using:

```js
const {
  query: {
    email,
    password
  }
} = useRouter()
```

I'm wondering if this is safe and a good practice, or if there is a better way?

[EDIT] Would it be safe to temporarily use `sessionstorage`?

Comment: Not a good idea to expose the password. You might want to read i to one time passwords or OTP for short :-) Edit: Ideally you shouldn't even have the users password saved in cleartext, but rather a salted and encrypted version of it.

Comment: @Boris I'm not saving it, I just want to pass it from the field in my login form to the one in my signup form